# Count number of occurrences of each word of text, display as circles of varying size

Tags: python, pygame

My focus was to have clean, structured code. It has to be efficient. The display doesn't have to look that good. The circles do overlap and sometimes the word doesn't fit inside the circle, but those are problems aren't really my concern right now and I will fix later.

**circle.py**

```
import pygame
import random

# Define the colors and screen sizes, define center

# Colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 128, 255)
red = (255, 102, 102)
green = (102, 255, 178)
purple = (178, 102, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 102)
colors = [blue, red, green, purple, yellow]
white = (255, 255, 255)

# Radius and font size
radius = [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

# Screen dimensions and title
SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 640, 480
CENTER = (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2)
TITLE = "Occurences"

# Actual screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

# Initialize screen
pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
screen.fill(white)

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, size, text):
        rand_color = random.randint(0, 4)
        rand_x = random.randint(size+5, SCREEN_WIDTH-size)
        rand_y = random.randint(size+5, SCREEN_HEIGHT-size)

        self.x = rand_x
        self.y = rand_y
        self.size = size
        self.color = colors[rand_color]
        self.screen = screen
        self.text = text

    def display(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.size)

        myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", self.size-15, bold=True)
        label = myfont.render(self.text, 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (self.x-self.size+10, self.y-20))
```

**occurences.py**

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import circle
import time
import re
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import Counter

# Intro
pygame.init()

intro_text = ["Hi!", "Welcome to 'occurences'!", "A program (with a misspelt name) that counts the number",
        "of occurrences in a piece of text", "and displays circles with sizes based on", "the number of occurrences of each word."]

for sentence in intro_text:
    print sentence 
    time.sleep(2)

text =  raw_input("Enter some text:\n") # Prompt the user for text

# Action!!!

#word_count = Counter(words) # Count them
#sorted_count = word_count.most_common() # Sort the count
#sorted_copy = sorted_count[:] # A copy of the sorted count, just in case

# Here's a one liner for the code above.
words = Counter(re.findall(r"[\w']+", text.lower())).most_common() # Split words

while words: # While the list of words isn't empty,
    max_occ = max(words, key=itemgetter(1))[1] # Take current max occurrence of the list

    for word in words:

        if word[1] == max_occ: # If the current word's occurrence is same as the max occurrence
            curr_word = word 

            if len(circle.radius) != 1:
                c = circle.Circle(circle.radius[-1], word[0]) # Draw a circle with the current largest size of circle.radius
                c.display() # Displaying the word on the circle
                circle.radius.pop() # Remove that current largest size
            else:
                c = circle.Circle(30, word[0]) # When there's only one size left (the smallest one), make all other words that size.
                c.display()

            words = [x for x in words if x != curr_word] # Change the list so that the words already dealt with are gone, making a new max_occ

pygame.display.flip()

# Event loop
running = 1
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = 0


pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

## Needless work to get in sorted order.

I'd like to take a look at the following section:

```
words = Counter(re.findall(r"[\w']+", text.lower())).most_common() # Split words

while words: # While the list of words isn't empty,
    max_occ = max(words, key=itemgetter(1))[1] # Take current max occurrence of the list

    for word in words:

        if word[1] == max_occ: # If the current word's occurrence is same as the max occurrence
            curr_word = word 

            if len(circle.radius) != 1:
                c = circle.Circle(circle.radius[-1], word[0]) # Draw a circle with the current largest size of circle.radius
                c.display() # Displaying the word on the circle
                circle.radius.pop() # Remove that current largest size
            else:
                c = circle.Circle(30, word[0]) # When there's only one size left (the smallest one), make all other words that size.
                c.display()

            words = [x for x in words if x != curr_word] # Change the list so that the words already dealt with are gone, making a new max_occ
```

First, let's look at the help of `most_common`:

```
most_common(self, n=None) unbound collections.Counter method
    List the n most common elements and their counts from the most
    common to the least.  If n is None, then list all element counts.
```

So, they are in exactly the order you want. Thus, we can replace some code

```
words = Counter(re.findall(r"[\w']+", text.lower())).most_common()
for word in words:
    if len(circle.radius) != 1:
        c = circle.Circle(circle.radius[-1], word[0]) # Draw a circle with the current largest size of circle.radius
        c.display() # Displaying the word on the circle
        circle.radius.pop() # Remove that current largest size
    else:
        c = circle.Circle(30, word[0]) # When there's only one size left (the smallest one), make all other words that size.
        c.display()
```

Notice how the while and if are now both gone? All because of how `.most_common` already guarantees they are ordered by max-occurence.

## Code duplication in getting the radius

Let's take a look at the inner `if`:

```
if len(circle.radius) != 1:
    c = circle.Circle(circle.radius[-1], word[0]) # Draw a circle with the current largest size of circle.radius
    c.display() # Displaying the word on the circle
    circle.radius.pop() # Remove that current largest size
else:
    c = circle.Circle(30, word[0]) # When there's only one size left (the smallest one), make all other words that size.
    c.display()
```

I'm going to do something sneaky: I see how the `circle.radius.pop()` and `c.display()` are unrelated, and that we can swap them.

```
if len(circle.radius) != 1:
    c = circle.Circle(circle.radius[-1], word[0]) # Draw a circle with the current largest size of circle.radius
    circle.radius.pop() # Remove that current largest size
    c.display() # Displaying the word on the circle
else:
    c = circle.Circle(30, word[0]) # When there's only one size left (the smallest one), make all other words that size.
    c.display()
```

Now, I see how both the branches of the `if` end with the same: the `c.display()` (and a comment which I'll ignore ;) ).

```
if len(circle.radius) != 1:
    c = circle.Circle(circle.radius[-1], word[0]) # Draw a circle with the current largest size of circle.radius
    circle.radius.pop() # Remove that current largest size
else:
    c = circle.Circle(30, word[0]) # When there's only one size left (the smallest one), make all other words that size.
c.display()
```

Another thing I'd like to note. `circle.radius.pop()` actually returns a value. What value? The *last* value in the list, that is `circle.radius[-1]`. Let's inline it.

```
if len(circle.radius) != 1:
    c = circle.Circle(circle.radius.pop(), word[0]) # Draw a circle with the current largest size of circle.radius
else:
    c = circle.Circle(30, word[0]) # When there's only one size left (the smallest one), make all other words that size.
c.display()
```

Ooh, see how they now have almost the same body? All that differs is the calculation of the radius. Let's move getting the radius outside of the construction of the circle.

```
if len(circle.radius) != 1:
    radius = circe.radius.pop()
    c = circle.Circle(radius, word[0]) # Draw a circle with the current largest size of circle.radius
else:
    radius = 30
    c = circle.Circle(radius, word[0]) # When there's only one size left (the smallest one), make all other words that size.
c.display()
```

and now we do the same trick as before: moving shared code outside of a branch

```
if len(circle.radius) != 1:
    radius = circe.radius.pop()
else:
    radius = 30
c = circle.Circle(radius, word[0])
c.display()
```

## Combining above results

```
words = Counter(re.findall(r"[\w']+", text.lower())).most_common()
for word in words:
    if len(circle.radius) != 1:
        radius = circle.radius.pop()
    else:
        radius = 30
    c = circle.Circle(radius, word[0])
    c.display()
```

Answer (score 1):

In **circle.py**:

```
# Colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 128, 255)
red = (255, 102, 102)
green = (102, 255, 178)
purple = (178, 102, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 102)
colors = [blue, red, green, purple, yellow]
white = (255, 255, 255)
```

Looking ahead at the rest of your code, you only use `white` and `black` individually. You could just create a variable for `white` and `black`, and the rest of the colours can be put in `colors`.

```
# Colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
colors = [
    black,
    (0, 128, 255),      # blue
    (255, 102, 102),    # red
    (102, 255, 178),    # green
    (178, 102, 255),    # purple
    (255, 255, 102)     # yellow
]
```

Some test data I ran to prove it (all values are in 3 S.F.):

```
            Original    Improved
Test 1      0.00299     0.00263
Test 2      0.00300     0.00283
Test 3      0.00302     0.00280
Min         0.00299     0.00263
```

Another thing I found in your code is this:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, size, text):
        rand_color = random.randint(0, 4)
        # code...

        self.color = colors[rand_color]
        # code...
```

The `random` library has a `.choice` function for choosing something in an array (a list or a tuple). Change it to just:

```
self.color = random.choice(colors)
```

Again, more data to prove it (The timing includes creating the variables with the optimized code above):

```
            Original    Improved
Test 1      0.0181       0.0102
Test 2      0.0187       0.0107
Test 3      0.0186       0.0102
Min         0.0181       0.0102
```

Now onto **occurences.py**:

I can only see a small problem which is as mentioned above:

```
intro_text = ["Hi!", "Welcome to 'occurences'!", "A program (with a misspelt name) that counts the number",
        "of occurrences in a piece of text", "and displays circles with sizes based on", "the number of occurrences of each word."]
```

Use tuples when your data does not change in size.

For the rest of the code, I don't see much that I can do here except formatting your comments properly. Quoting from [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Use inline comments sparingly.

and also:

> Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.

The above includes comments too.

Comment: About the remark "Use tuples when your data does not change in size.". I know a lot of programmers who disagree: tuples should be used for structured data, not just for 'lists but more speedy'. For white/black/green/... they make sense. For a list of colors, it does not. A list is a list, and you should not abuse a tuple "because it's faster". There is a semantic difference.